# How do I merge two XML files into one using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have two XML files and want to merge them, but the tags that are already there should not be changed:

XML 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<formX xmlns="sdu:x">
  <identify>
    <mat>8</mat>
  </identify>
</formX>
```

XML 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<formX xmlns="sdu:x">
  <identify>
    <mat>9999</mat>
    <name>John Smith</name>
  </identify>
</formX>
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<formX xmlns="sdu:x">
  <identify>
    <mat>8</mat>
    <name>John Smith</name>
  </identify>
</formX>
```

The previous tags should have the same values but with the addition of the new ones.
Is that possible using Nokogiri? How?

At first I tried without Nokogiri using:

```
xml1 = Hash.from_xml('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<formX xmlns="sdu:x">
  <identify>
    <mat>8</mat>
  </identify>
</formX>')
```

But when I convert back to xml (xml1.to_xml) I get in wrong format:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<hash>\n  <formX>\n    <xmlns>sdu:x</xmlns>\n    <identify>\n      <mat>8</mat>\n    </identify>\n  </formX>\n</hash>\n"
```

Using Nokogiri, I came up with this solution, but really, it is so ugly and have a bug. If the xml2 doesnt have a element it will crash:

```
require 'nokogiri'

s = "<formAposentadoria xmlns=\"spu:aposentadoria\"><identificacao><matricula>8</matricula></identificacao></formAposentadoria>"
xml1 = Nokogiri::XML.parse s

s2 = "<formAposentadoria xmlns=\"spu:aposentadoria\"><identificacao><matricula>9</matricula><nome>John</nome></identificacao></formAposentadoria>"
xml2 = Nokogiri::XML.parse s2

def node_list elem, &proc
  return [] unless elem.class == Nokogiri::XML::Element
  str = proc.call(elem)
  [str] + elem.children.inject([]){|a,c| a+node_list(c,&proc)}.map{|e| "#{str}/#{e}"}
end

node_list(xml1.root){|e| e.name}.each do |x|
  caminho = '//xmlns:' + x.gsub('/', '/xmlns:')
  puts caminho
  if xml2.at_xpath( caminho ).children.children.count == 0
    xml2.at_xpath( caminho ).content = xml1.at_xpath( caminho ).content
  end
end

puts xml2.to_xml
```

Comment: What have you tried? On Stack Overflow it's expected you have tried to solve this yourself, and to show your code and give an explanation why it didn't work.

Comment: I tried many codes, but no good results. That's why I didnt put any code but what I want from result.

Comment: And that exactly the point why you're supposed to show us what you tried. It's immensely easier for us to check your work and then show you what's wrong so you can immediately incorporate that into your application, than it is for us to write working code, explain how it works, and then have you *try* to insert it into your code with modified variables and structures. Plus, there's the whole aspect of showing that you put some effort into the question. We need to see proof. Stack Overflow isn't a "I need code written for me" site.

Comment: All right. You are right and I will put all my tries.

Comment: How do you want tag-collisions to be handled? First one wins? Last one wins? Create an array of the values for the colliding tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your samples and the desired output it appears you just want to replace the `mat` value in XML2 with the `mat` value from XML1.

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml1 = Nokogiri::XML('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<formX xmlns="sdu:x">
  <identify>
    <mat>8</mat>
  </identify>
</formX>')

xml2 = Nokogiri::XML('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<formX xmlns="sdu:x">
  <identify>
    <mat>9999</mat>
    <name>John Smith</name>
  </identify>
</formX>')

xml2.at('mat').content = xml1.at('mat').content

puts xml2.to_xml
```

Which outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<formX xmlns="sdu:x">
  <identify>
    <mat>8</mat>
    <name>John Smith</name>
  </identify>
</formX>
```

This isn't really a merge, it's a simple substitution. If there is more to the problem then your examples and desired output need to be modified to be more comprehensive.

Comment: That's good but I want that with any tag. Not just the 'mat'.

Comment: Then you need to provide accurate sample XML input and a desired output XML that represents what you really want. We can't read your mind.