# How do I merge elements from two XML files into one based on id using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm trying to build off of a previously asked question ([How do I merge two XML files into one using Nokogiri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700210/how-do-i-merge-two-xml-files-into-one-using-nokogiri)), but I'm having some difficulty.

I would like to import the content of "mat" from the first XML file into the second XML file only if the element ids match. This is what I have so far...

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml1 = Nokogiri::XML('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<formX xmlns="sdu:x">
  <identify>
    <mat id="a">8</mat>
  </identify>
  <identify>
    <mat id="b">7</mat>
  </identify>  
</formX>')

xml2 = Nokogiri::XML('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<formX xmlns="sdu:x">
  <identify>
    <mat id="a">9999</mat>
    <name>John Smith</name>
  </identify>
  <identify>
    <mat id="b">9999</mat>
    <name>Jane Smith</name>
  </identify>  
</formX>')

xml2.css('mat').each do |node|
  if xml2.at('mat')['id'] == xml1.at('mat')['id']
    node.content = xml1.at('mat').content
  end
end

puts xml2.to_xml
```

And, I receive the following output...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<formX xmlns="sdu:x">
  <identify>
    <mat id="a">8</mat>
    <name>John Smith</name>
  </identify>
  <identify>
    <mat id="b">8</mat>
    <name>Jane Smith</name>
  </identify>  
</formX>
```

But, I'm shooting for...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<formX xmlns="sdu:x">
  <identify>
    <mat id="a">8</mat>
    <name>John Smith</name>
  </identify>
  <identify>
    <mat id="b">7</mat>
    <name>Jane Smith</name>
  </identify>  
</formX>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you find the same id element is not right.
This works:

```
xml2.css('mat').each do |node2|
  xml1.css('mat').each do |node1|
    if node1['id'] == node2['id']
      node2.content = node1.content
    end 
  end 
end
puts xml2.to_xml
```

Comment: Don't just hand out code, explain *why* it works so the OP doesn't make the same mistake again.

Comment: I think I've already make a short and clear explanation on why his code did not work in my first sentence.

Comment: This code could be made much more performant by caching a hash mapping the id to the `mat` element, and then re-using that in the inner loop. This would turn the performance from O(m*n) to O(m+n).